# I have a txt file of only file locations and I need to find the size of each file then add them up using powershell

Tags: powershell, filesize

I feel like all I do on here is ask questions because I don't have enough skills to answer any yet, so I am very grateful for all your help everyone.

I need to know please, I have a txt file that has one file location on each line.
I need to go through the txt file using powershell scripting and get the file size of each location (which are all .pst files by the way).

Once I have all the file sizes, I need to add them up to get the size of all files (it doesn't necessarily need to list each file size), I basically just need the total, and then put the total in a variable.

This is part of a backup script where I am checking to ensure that the data size is smaller than the size of the USB they will be backing up to.

Thanks for all your help everyone.

I very much appreciate it.

I feel like it has something to do with Get-Content and ForEach-Object but I can't seem to get my head around the syntax, to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Contents of file***
D:\software\en_office_professional_plus_2013_x64_dvd_1123674.iso
D:\software\en_windows_8_1_x64_dvd_2707217.iso

***Script***

```
$total_size = 0

Get-Content D:\code\ps\sample.txt | % {    
   $obj = New-Object -TypeName system.io.FileInfo($_)
   $total_size += $obj.Length / 1GB
}

$total_size
```

***Output***
4.38277816772461